# Angular 7 - Creating an Accordion Menu

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 7 and creating an accordion navigation menu.

On click of an H2 it calls the **navSelect(item, $event)** method in the nav.component.ts.

In this method, I would like it to:
1.) Remove the class "opened" on all the H2 with a class of ".acc_trigger".
2.) Add the class "opened" to the H2 that called the method.

If you view the navSelect() method below you will notice what I have. I'm kinda close, but not all there. I can't get all the 'h2.acc_trigger' to remove the class "opened"...

***EDIT - the below code now works well.

nav.component.html

```
<nav id="main-menu" *ngIf="nav">
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of nav.Navigation.MenuItem; let r = index">
    <h2 class="acc_trigger" (click)="navSelect(item, $event)" >{{item.Text}}</h2>
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.MenuItem != null">
        <div class="acc_container" >
            <ul class="ulNav">
                <li *ngFor="let nav of item.MenuItem"><a href="">{{nav.Text}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

nav.component.ts

```
navSelect(item: any, e: any,) {

  var h2e = (e.target as Element);

    if(this.lastH2Selected != undefined) {
        var lastH2Sibling = (this.lastH2Selected as Element).nextElementSibling;
        if(lastH2Sibling != null) {
            lastH2Sibling.classList.remove("opened");
        }
    }

    if(h2e.nextElementSibling != null) {
        h2e.nextElementSibling.classList.add('opened');
    }

    //store off
    this.lastH2Selected = h2e;

}
```

nav.component.css

```
div.acc_container {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: ease-out 300ms max-height;
}

div.acc_container.opened {
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: ease-in 600ms max-height;
}
```

Comment: Could you have a public variable that stores the h2 which you most recently clicked, then use that to check which h2 should use the opened class?

Comment: [angular.element()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) is an AngularJS (1.x) API and cannot be used in Angular 2+. If you need to execute DOM manipulation you should be using [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) and [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) services injected into the respective component/directive. You should first attempt to use those services then update your question accordingly if you are still having issues.

Comment: but can you use ElementRef for all H2 elements? I've used that to reference single elements only. Could you please show some code on how I would do this. I and others would be most thankful.

Comment: You can execute DOM query methods such as `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` against the element reference `this.injectedElementReferenceName.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('h2')`. That being said you consider tracking opened/closed accordion elements via properties on the respective classes and/or services. If each accordion element is a component, it can have it's own opened state and can communicate with parent/siblings via a number of mechanisms. At minimum, you should create something on StackBlitz or similar to allow others to contribute. Thanks!

Comment: I cleaned up the code, so it now works well.